# Called reloadData from collectionView::didEndDisplayingCell. It causes the app to freeze. Why?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

Here is my pseduo code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"didEndDisplayingCell %@", indexPath );
    if (collectionView == self.viewA) {
        ...
        cities_in_viewB = [NSArray arrayWithArray:all_cities_subset];
        __weak UICollectionView* weak_viewB = self.viewB;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
           [weak_viewB reloadData];
        });
    }
}
```

After `reloadData` is called, the ios App appears to be frozen. Why?

**EDIT**

Based on Oleg Sobolev's answer, I have refactored the code and found the problem is not related to recursion. As you can see in the sample code about, it is `viewB` getting the reload call. viewA, inside this `didEndDisplayingCell`, is not affected.

What happened is that I have a `while` loop in the code (not shown) to prepare a new set of data for `viewB`. The exit condition was written badly.

However, I would still like to see a possible solution if recursion is a problem.

Comment: I did answer at your question? You just make recursion in lifecycle of view controller.

Comment: Sorry, I find out a root cause and it is not related to recursive call. I will put down more details in the question

Comment: This function will called for **each** item in your collectionView. I think problem is you have a lot of items in viewA. So, you got heavy calculating. And you should not use main_queue for heavy calculation, cuz interface drawing occurs in this queue.

Comment: Try to use background queue.

Comment: Is dispatch_async considered a background queue?

Comment: Try to use. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)`

Comment: Any feedback? Anyway i think that is a bad idea, if you have a lot of items in view A or in viewA and in viewB.

Comment: @OlegSobolev Thanks for following it up. Sorry, since my problem is not really recursion related I don't think I can prove it But thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. Really appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursion =) reload data -> itemAtIndex -> will display -> did display

Maybe i lose something in this cycle, but it does not matter. `reload data` call `did display` method, and you try to call `reload data` method in `did display` method =)

**EDIT**

This answer is not more valid for updated question.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your answer. Sorry for needing to change the question which renders your answer irrelevant.